# Websphere MQ: Limit max messages consumed in a distributed environment

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq, distributed

I have WAS 6.1 on `n` physical nodes, one Application Server `(AS)` for each node. I have a queue implemented in Websphere MQ which is consumed by an MDB pool (one for each server).

I need, in some specific cases, to limit the number of messages consumed to a number `m`, with `m` possibly lesser than `n`. (This is because each consumed message produces a call to an external system which could have overload issues).

Now I know I can do this in each `AS` separately, but what if `m<n` and I want my MQ, in simple words, to work as in a monolithic environment? Is there some "shared configuration" I can do?

Comment: Are all of these MDBs consuming from the same queue?

Comment: Yes, they are. Or at least I need the same behaviour for each involved queue/mdb pool.